# How can I inject dependencies into my angular controller neatly?

Tags: angularjs

I have:

```
app.controller('ReportsCtrl', ['$scope', 'reportsApiCall', 'analyticsInitialiserClient', '$timeout', 'chart', 'originCompositionChart', 'executionTimeChart', 'cacheCompositionChart', function ($scope, reportsApiCall, analyticsInitialiserClient, $timeout, chart, originCompositionChart, executionTimeChart, cacheCompositionChart) {
```

But I like the syntax of using. `myController.$inject = ['$scope','notify'];`

But I don't want to declare the name of myController, because then I'm polluting the global namespace. Is there a way I can go: ?

```
app.controller('ReportsCtrl', function ($scope, reportsApiCall, analyticsInitialiserClient, $timeout, chart, originCompositionChart, executionTimeChart, cacheCompositionChart) {
}).$inject();
```

Because that syntax is failing for me at the moment :( ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
(function(){
     myController.$inject = ['service1','service2'];
     function myController(s1,s2){
         //controller logic
     }
     app.controller('myCtrl',myController);
}());
```

Comment: Also, here's a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/12/01/structuring-angularjs-code.aspx) that actually talks about this as a coding style for your entire app..

Answer (score 1):

I use [grunt-ngmin](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) to annotate my source code when it's minified and just don't place annontations in my code directly.

Comment: Yes, stop declaring manually these things when a script could automatically do it.